# How to Call PUT Request in IOS and need to pass a Dictionary

Tags: ios, web-services

This is my json Dictionary

```
{"pid":"14982","type":"intervention","uid":"10008","bookmark_g7l03":{"und":[{"value":"S:1","format":"null","safe_value":"S:1"}]}}
```

I need to pass the PUT request to the following URL

```
http://example.com/services/profiles/pid
```

Let us know how to pass the dictionary to Webservice URL in IOS

```
NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"pid\":\"%@\",\"type\":\"%@\",\"uid\":\"%@\",\"%@\":{\"und\":\[{\"value\":\"%@\",\"format\":\"null\",\"safe_value\":\"\%@\"}]}}",pid,type, uidNo,bkMarkStr,self.startString,self.startString];
NSURL *bkMrkUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/services/profiles/pid=14997"];
NSData *postData = [data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSMutableURLRequest *bkMrkReq = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:bkMrkUrl];
[bkMrkReq setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];
[bkMrkReq setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[bkMrkReq setHTTPBody:postData];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:bkMrkReq queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                           completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {


                               NSString *txt = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

                               NSLog(@"data....:%@",txt);

                               // handle response here
                           }];
```

Here, When i Print the text data

Output is: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<result>CSRF validation failed</result>`

What should i do with the data..
Here am updating the fields info in server.

Comment: Checkout AFNetworking http://afnetworking.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://example.com/services/profiles/pid"]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"PUT"];

NSString *params = @"\{\"pid\" : \"14997\", \"type\" : \"intervention\", \"uid\" : \"10046\"}"; // The rest of your parmas here

[request setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue currentQueue]
                       completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
                           // handle response here
                       }];
```

If you want to make the request synchronously instead you can use:

```
NSURLResponse *response;
NSError *error;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
```

Comment: @Olllie, how we can see the response

Comment: I am getting the data.., let us know how to use that data

Comment: Do you know what format the data is in? If it is JSON you can use: `NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];`

Comment: If you use that code in the comment above in the completion handler of the request. (Where is says "`//handle response here`) it will convert the response from your data request to a JSON dictionary. From here you can perform whatever action you need on the response.

Comment: Inside the completion handler, replace `// handle response here` and change it with `if (connectionError) { // there was an error } else { // PUT was sent}` This will tell you if the request was sent successfully or not. Typically in a request you will receive information back confirming this and that will be in the JSON Dictionary I mentioned earlier